# Python: the system cannot find the file specified using subprocess.Popen

Tags: python

The entirety of my script:

```
#!/bin/env python

import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash", "-i", "-c", "C:\\xampp\\xampp_stop.exe"])
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
```

This results in: `WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified`

However, `C:\xampp\xampp_stop.exe` does exist

Any suggestions? I'm new to python, so I suspect it's something very, very obvious.

Comment: I guess it can't find `/bin/bash`. You can Probably just call `subprocess.Popen(["C:\\xampp\\xampp_stop.exe"])` - I haven't tested it though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's actually `bash` that the system can't find. Windows doesn't come with `bash`. Remove it and its arguments and just call `xampp_store.exe`.

```
#!/bin/env python

import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(["C:\\xampp\\xampp_stop.exe"])
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. (I'm actually using MINGW32, so I thought that would work since bash is available, but your solution does work)

Comment: You need to run python from cygwin for that. Otherwise, it won't be able to map /bin/bash to where you installed bash.exe.